# Match both of these with regex, not just one of

Tags: regex

I'm looking in a sql table through a bunch of names and I want to get a list of all the different titles used. e.g. SNR, MRS, MR, JNR etc

Sometimes there is an entry that might have 2 titles, e.g:  MR NAME NAME JNR. I want both of these titles 'MR' & 'JNR'

I thought a good way to do this would be with regex and find any names that have 2 or 3 characters. A title at the front would be followed by a space, while a title at the end would be preceded by one. So I have:

```
/(^[A-Z]{2,3})\s|\s(^[A-Z]{2,3}$)/
```

[a regex101 example here](https://regex101.com/r/iQ2dB6/2).

As you can see I've used 'match either A or B' thing. If I throw at it a name with a title at either the start or finish, I end up getting what I want, but I don't know how to tell it to get both. i.e. strings with 2 titles will only give me back one match.

How do I get both?

Comment: Have you tried [`\b[A-Z]{2,3}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/iQ2dB6/3)

Comment: no I have not @anubhava. because I am not a wizard. thank you

Comment: I did not realise as well that using the g modifier also helps my query to work, whether it is correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an "OR", you could just match any character in between:

[`(^[A-Z]{3})\s.*\s([A-Z]{3}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/iQ2dB6/4)